# Where can I find the linker command file for the MSP430G2553?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, embedded, msp430

I'm using the MSPGCC to compile and link my programs.  I'd like to see how the hardware addresses are assigned in the linker command file.  Inside the header file for my device I found these lines:

```
/* External references resolved by a device-specific linker command file */
#define SFR_8BIT(address)   extern volatile unsigned char address
#define SFR_16BIT(address)  extern volatile unsigned int address
```

Further on in the file I found lines like this under the GPIO section:

```
SFR_8BIT(P1IN);                               /* Port 1 Input */
SFR_8BIT(P1OUT);                              /* Port 1 Output */
SFR_8BIT(P1DIR);                              /* Port 1 Direction */
SFR_8BIT(P1IFG);                              /* Port 1 Interrupt Flag */
```

What I'd like to see is how P1IN is defined.  I'm trying to get a better understanding of what it is so I can use it.

I realize it can be used like this:

```
P1OUT &= 0xF7; // clear bit 3
```

I'd like to find the linker file so I can better understand how the address is being assigned.  I know I can just look at the data sheet to see what it is, but I'd like to know how the linker is finding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined in the file `msp430g2553.cmd`.

```
/************************************************************
* DIGITAL I/O Port1/2 Pull up / Pull down Resistors
************************************************************/
P1IN               = 0x0020;
P1OUT              = 0x0021;
...
```

PS: I'm using CCS. The file is located at `path\to\ccs\ccs_base\msp430\include` along with the header file `msp430g2553.h`.

Comment: I assume that this file instructs the linker to associate the name with the memory location, I just wanted to see if there was anything fancy going on and it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @tylerjw Probably what you're searching for: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984214/embedded-c-registers-access)